# Angular 4: unable to create object of a component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am using a 3rd party component which is responsible to upload files. I am importing this component in my component as below, but the problem is I am never going inside the `if` loop. Can anyone guide me how to create an object of `UploadComp`?

```
import { UploadComp } from com.package.folder;

export class showUpload {
    @ViewChild (UploadComp) uploadCompObj: UploadComp;


constructor(){
    if(this.uploadCompObj){     //I am never going inside this if
        this.uploadCompObj.popup = true;
    }
} }
```

The upload component is as below:

```
export declare class UploadComp implements Oninit{
    popup: boolean;
    overlay: boolean;
    fileName: string;
    errorMsg: any[];
}
```

Comment: Also note that your `constructor` isn't within class boundries

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti ohhh yes that was a typo error, I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use AfterViewInit() life cycle and use the if condition

```
import { UploadComp } from com.package.folder;

        export class showUpload {
            @ViewChild (UploadComp) uploadCompObj: UploadComp;
        }

        constructor(){}
        ngAfterViewInit() {
           if(this.uploadCompObj){     //I am never going inside this if
                this.uploadCompObj.popup = true;
            }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use angular lifecycle hook. Constructor gets called before angular settle down. So use the `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(this.uploadCompObj){      
        this.uploadCompObj.popup = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried calling it inside ngOnInit() still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: try `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild()` is not a part of importing component class it is a part of getting the child component from your `component.html`

I have couple of changes for you if it works great use it

Remove your `@ViewChild()` from the component class and your code should read like this -

```
uploadCompObj: UploadComp = {
    popup: true,
    overlay: true,
    fileName: null,
    errorMsg: null
};
```

Next you need to remove `declare` from the component class you are trying to import - I'm not sure why you used declare but just by exporting a component class you can create an object, if its not an error prob please don't remove it

Now finally you can set value to your properties both in `constructor` and `onInit()` but the best practice is to change value in your `onInit()` try to access there - hope it works

Thanks - Happy coding !!